# How to apply data table .I function to only specific elements in data table?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we generate the following data table by running the simple `data.table` code shown immediately beneath, where the code numbers each element in the data table (`Nbr` column) and further letter-counts each element of same `ID` (`Class` column):

```
> DT
   ID Nbr Class
1:  A   1     A
2:  A   2     B
3:  B   3     A
4:  C   4     A
5:  D   5     A

DT <- data.table(ID = c("A","A","B","C","D")) 
DT[, c("Nbr", "Class") := .(.I, LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]), by = ID]
```

How would I modify the above, using `data.table`, so for example the `Class` designation ignores all `ID` elements = B, instead assigning all B elements an `NA`? I'd rather figure out how to do this in `data.table` rather than my neophyte reaction of just replacing via base R or using `dplyr`, since I'm trying to learn how to use `data.table`. So the results would look like this:

```
> DT
   ID Nbr Class
1:  A   1     A
2:  A   2     B
3:  B   3     NA
4:  C   4     A
5:  D   5     A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(data.table)
DT[][ID == "B", Class := NA]
DT
```

Output:

```
   ID Nbr Class
1:  A   1     A
2:  A   2     B
3:  B   3  <NA>
4:  C   4     A
5:  D   5     A
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
DT[, c("Nbr", "Class") := .(.I, LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]), by = ID]
```

To this

```
DT[, c("Nbr", "Class") := .(.I, if (ID == "B") NA else LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]), ID]
```

Full code

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c("A","A","B","C","D"))
DT[, c("Nbr", "Class") := .(.I, if (ID == "B") NA else LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]), ID]
DT
#>    ID Nbr Class
#> 1:  A   1     A
#> 2:  A   2     B
#> 3:  B   3  <NA>
#> 4:  C   4     A
#> 5:  D   5     A
```

Second example

```
DT[, c("Nbr", "Class") := .(.I, if (ID < "E" && ID > "B") NA else LETTERS[seq_len(.N)]), ID]
DT
#>    ID Nbr Class
#> 1:  A   1     A
#> 2:  A   2     B
#> 3:  B   3     A
#> 4:  C   4  <NA>
#> 5:  D   5  <NA>
```